# after migrating from spring 2 to spring 3: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException

Tags: spring, hibernate

full stack trace of exception:

```
ERROR CheckboxTag:86 - Property not found
org.springframework.binding.expression.PropertyNotFoundException: Property not found
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValueType(SpringELExpression.java:103)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.BindingModel.getFormattedValue(BindingModel.java:228)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.BindingModel.getFieldValue(BindingModel.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractCheckedElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractCheckedElementTag.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractSingleCheckedElementTag.writeTagContent(AbstractSingleCheckedElementTag.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxTag.writeTagContent(CheckboxTag.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.Location_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fcheckbox_005f3(Location_jsp.java:2283)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.Location_jsp._jspService(Location_jsp.java:648)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.ServletMvcView.doRender(ServletMvcView.java:55)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:187)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:296)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.doEnter(ViewState.java:186)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:535)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:366)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.start(RequestControlContextImpl.java:234)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.SubflowState.doEnter(SubflowState.java:101)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'aHCS' cannot be found on object of type 'ca.ups.tundra.model.Location'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:208)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:72)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValueType(SpelExpression.java:117)
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValueType(SpringELExpression.java:100)
    ... 103 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this happens when we have contrasting property names in hibernate config file and model class with getter and setter methods.